# My game crashes on reopen but not immediately

Tags: java, android

I've done a good search and have been trying a lot of stuff but no matter what I try to do it just won't work, the game runs fine on startup! But refuses to run once I close and reopen. It doesn't need to continue, I'd be happy with it restarting. The crash log tells me it's something to do with my thread. But I really can't find a damn thing. Any help or suggestions would be great.

// Game Thread

```
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class GameThread extends Thread {

    private boolean running;
    private GameSurface gameSurface;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private Object mPauseLock = new Object();
    private boolean mPaused;

    public GameThread(GameSurface gameSurface, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)  {
        this.gameSurface= gameSurface;
        this.surfaceHolder= surfaceHolder;
    }



    @Override
    public void run()  {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        while(running)  {
            Canvas canvas= null;
            try {
                // Get Canvas from Holder and lock it.
                canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();

                // Synchronized
                synchronized (canvas)  {
                    this.gameSurface.update();
                    this.gameSurface.draw(canvas);
                }
            }catch(Exception e)  {
                // Do nothing.
            } finally {
                if(canvas!= null)  {
                    // Unlock Canvas.
                    this.surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }

            long now = System.nanoTime() ;
            // Interval to redraw game
            // (Change nanoseconds to milliseconds)
            long waitTime = (now - startTime)/1000000;
            if(waitTime < 10)  {
                waitTime= 10; // Millisecond.
            }
            System.out.print(" Wait Time="+ waitTime);

            try {
                // Sleep.
                this.sleep(waitTime);
            } catch(InterruptedException e)  {

            }

            synchronized (mPauseLock) {
                while (mPaused) {
                    try {
                        mPauseLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){

                    }
                }
            }
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.print(".");
        }
    }

    public void onPause() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = true;
        }
    }

    public void onResume() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = false;
            mPauseLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }


    public void setRunning(boolean running)  {
        this.running= running;
    }
}
```

//GameSurface

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private GameThread gameThread;
    private Player player;
    private boolean mGameIsRunning;

    public GameSurface(Context context)  {
        super(context);

        // Make Game Surface focusable so it can handle events. .
        this.setFocusable(true);

        // Sét callback.
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    public void update()  {
        this.player.update();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            player.setActionDown();
            int movingVectorX =x-  this.player.getX() ;
            int movingVectorY =y-  this.player.getY() ;
            this.player.setMovingVector(movingVectorX,movingVectorY);
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    player.setactionUp();
                }
            }, 100);
            return true;
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            player.setactionUp();
        }
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)  {
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));
        this.player.draw(canvas);
    }

    // Implements method of SurfaceHolder.Callback
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Bitmap playerbitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.player);
        this.player = new Player(this,playerbitmap,100,50);

        this.gameThread = new GameThread(this,holder);

        if (gameThread.getState() == Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) {
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
        } else if (gameThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
        } else {
            this.gameThread.setRunning(true);
            this.gameThread.start();
            start();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        if(!mGameIsRunning) {
            gameThread.start();
            mGameIsRunning = true;
        } else {
            gameThread.onResume();
        }
    }

    // Implements method of SurfaceHolder.Callback
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    }

    // Implements method of SurfaceHolder.Callback
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry= true;
        while(retry) {
            try {
                this.gameThread.setRunning(false);

                // Parent thread must wait until the end of GameThread.
                this.gameThread.join();
            }catch(InterruptedException e)  {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            retry= true;
        }
    }

}
```

The :

```
if (gameThread.getState() == Thread.State.TIMED_WAITING) {
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
        } else if (gameThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
            gameThread.setRunning(false);
        } else {
            this.gameThread.setRunning(true);
            this.gameThread.start();
            start();
        }
```

was my last attempt at trying to get it to work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you for any help in advance.

// Log:

```
12-11 07:10:39.631 E/AndroidRuntime(6488): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
12-11 07:10:39.631 E/AndroidRuntime(6488): Process: archtectsproductions.endlessrunner, PID: 6488
12-11 07:10:39.631 E/AndroidRuntime(6488): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference
12-11 07:10:39.631 E/AndroidRuntime(6488):  at archtectsproductions.endlessrunner.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:67)
12-11 07:10:39.631 E/AndroidRuntime(6488):  at archtectsproductions.endlessrunner.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:28)
12-11 07:10:41.250 E/AndroidRuntime(6515): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
12-11 07:10:41.250 E/AndroidRuntime(6515): Process: archtectsproductions.endlessrunner, PID: 6515
12-11 07:10:41.250 E/AndroidRuntime(6515): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference
12-11 07:10:41.250 E/AndroidRuntime(6515):  at archtectsproductions.endlessrunner.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:67)
12-11 07:10:41.250 E/AndroidRuntime(6515):  at archtectsproductions.endlessrunner.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:28)
12-11 07:10:48.881 E/AndroidRuntime(6573): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
12-11 07:10:48.881 E/AndroidRuntime(6573): Process: archtectsproductions.endlessrunner, PID: 6573
12-11 07:10:48.881 E/AndroidRuntime(6573): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference
12-11 07:10:48.881 E/AndroidRuntime(6573):  at archtectsproductions.endlessrunner.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:67)
12-11 07:10:48.881 E/AndroidRuntime(6573):  at archtectsproductions.endlessrunner.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:28)
12-11 08:06:05.357 E/AndroidRuntime(9121): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
12-11 08:06:05.357 E/AndroidRuntime(9121): Process: archtectsproductions.myapplication, PID: 9121
12-11 08:06:05.357 E/AndroidRuntime(9121): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference
12-11 08:06:05.357 E/AndroidRuntime(9121):  at archtectsproductions.myapplication.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:84)
12-11 08:06:05.357 E/AndroidRuntime(9121):  at archtectsproductions.myapplication.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:28)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015): Process: archtectsproductions.walkingtest, PID: 12015
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015): java.lang.AssertionError: Attempt to repark
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2143)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:840)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:873)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1197)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:185)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:262)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.internalLockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:999)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at android.view.SurfaceView$4.lockCanvas(SurfaceView.java:975)
12-11 08:32:09.819 E/AndroidRuntime(12015):     at archtectsproductions.walkingtest.GameThread.run(GameThread.java:31)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071): Process: archtectsproductions.walkingtest, PID: 14071
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Thread$State java.lang.Thread.getState()' on a null object reference
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at archtectsproductions.walkingtest.GameSurface.surfaceCreated(GameSurface.java:68)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:632)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:162)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:944)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2239)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1280)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6432)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6321)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
12-11 08:50:28.534 E/AndroidRuntime(14071):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
12-11 09:41:56.793 D/AndroidRuntime(19572): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
12-11 09:41:56.795 D/AndroidRuntime(19572): CheckJNI is OFF
12-11 09:41:56.906 D/AndroidRuntime(19572): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
12-11 09:41:56.917 D/AndroidRuntime(19572): Shutting down VM
12-11 09:41:57.187 D/AndroidRuntime(19586): >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 0 <<<<<<
12-11 09:41:57.189 D/AndroidRuntime(19586): CheckJNI is OFF
12-11 09:41:57.315 D/AndroidRuntime(19586): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
```

Comment: Post your error log here.

Comment: @R.R.M posted its not liking a thread and idk why

Comment: I think this line is producing null pointer exception :  canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#eeeeee"));

Comment: @R.R.M do you think that could be the cause of the game not reopening properly?

Comment: Yes. It can cause crash of app. Try commenting that line

Comment: I have commented it out but it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: Your gameThread variable is null.

Comment: @R.M.M im not allowed to awnser my question but i have solved it now thank you. I started playing with the Destroy Function so I ripped it to peaces and started again with it and now on destroy it calls my on resume function ....
And it works perfectly Sorry to anyone who wasted their time trying to help me with a solution Im such a donut. Ive also started sorting the null gamethread var

Comment: That's great..!

Comment: @R.R.M Ye only i have a new error now, after about 1 min or so it crashes. complaining about my unlock canvas and post.

Comment: What is error log?

Comment: @R.R.M Dw I sorted it. It basically was crashing because of my canvas unlock and post. But the issue had nothing to do with that. It was because I was calling start in my game thread and q start method in my game surface. Because reasons.